# C# - .NET - MSTest - Test context - Add result file - Selenium Screenshots - Issue while viewing the result file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, mstest, testcontext

I have a Selenium test automation suite ( in MS Stack )  where I take a screenshot for every test ( incase of failure ) and try attaching to the test result.

I am using this solution to attach the screenshot to the result file.

[c# - selenium - MSTest - Unable to add a result file ( using testcontext.AddResultFile ) to the report using testcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450326/c-sharp-selenium-mstest-unable-to-add-a-result-file-using-testcontext-ad)

The issue I am facing is say , if I have 20 test failures out of 150 tests, 
I have 20 screenshots ( which is expected ) but all these 20 screenshots get displayed for each of the failures.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here..

It looks very ugly when all the test fails as all the 150 screenshots are attached to each of the individual test

Any idea to over come this?

Thanks
[image]